# How do I integrate dart on the front end and codeigniter on the server?

Tags: codeigniter, dart

So I have just come across google dart which looks like an amazing alternative to javascript. I'm wondering how can I integrate dart for front-end coding with codeigniter on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I know Dart but not CodeIgniter. What features do you want to use?

Usually you build your client in Dart and communicate with the server using HttpRequests or WebSocket. You build your Dart client to JavaScript and copy the output to the static files directory of your server.

It might be a bit more complicated during development because you usually don't want to run the build output during development but pure Dart.

The official solution is to use a proxy during development (standalone or integrated in your server) which forwards access to Dart-related static content to `pub serve` (a Dart development web server which does some pre-processing or on-the-fly to-JavaScript transpilation) instead of serving it from disk like it would be in production.